# How to generate graphql.schema from models?

Tags: graphql, apollo, graphql-js, relay, prisma-graphql

Creating and maintaining `graphql.schema` which includes all Queries, Mutations, relations, filters, etc. is not easy to be done manually.
Is there a tool I can use to generate `graphql.schema` from model objects or database schema, or type?
the tools I found so far do not generate schema, or does not generate interface, or their filter are lacking many attributes such as `gte lte notIn cursor, etc.`

currently found resources:
graphback, relay, apollo, dgs, ts-graphql